# Stuck; Text Wrapping Very Strangely In A Div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a view for an ASP.NET MVC app and I have a loop that creates a button for each item in a list of category names. Each button is a box 125px x 125px. However, sometimes the category name is longer than the button. I want to get the text to wrap within the box. Right now, it's wrapping, but outside of the box. I'm not really sure how to fix this. I suspect it has something to do with the 'wrap' section. I've added images of what this looks like.

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PTPc.png)

[Strange text wrapping revealed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9X7I.png)

CSHTML:

```
<section class="wrap">

        @foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
        {
            <a role="button" href="#@cat.Replace(" ", "_")" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@category.Replace(" ", "_")">
                <div class="category-box">
                    <b>@category</b>
                </div>
            </a>
        }
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
.category-box{

    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: rgb(70, 158, 165);
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 125px;   
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.category-box:hover{

    background-color: rgb(70, 104, 165);
    color: white;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 95vh; 
  width: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.wrap a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line height is a problem. Unset it or set to 1.2em for optimum view. 
And I recommend delete the `<div>` inside anchor and set anchor to `inline-block`.

Comment: this works to wrap the text inside the div, but now it doesn't sit in the center of the box:

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I can't edit my previous comment. Here is what it looks like: http://imgur.com/a/Ab8kF

Comment: I recommend something like this for text container: `display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center`

Comment: Align will center vertically and justify horizontally.